# mysql cluster lost data after restore

Tags: mysql, restore

all,

I use mysqldump to backup mysql cluster data with 10 million lines data daily. Recently, our cluster is crashed after a update, then we restore the .sql file generated by mysqldump. When restoring the database, we got key duplication errors/problem, and then I use "-f" to force the restore process. And finally, the restore process completed and all tables is back. Some tables are smaller, we think that is because the duplicate lines are ignored.

But recently, we find some data is missing, it seems that some duplicated data dose not restored correctly.

May I know whether there is a nice way to avoid this in restore process or how to check whether we have duplication before mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions - take a look at the errors that are generated when not using the force option and see if you can figure out how to fix the root cause. Using the force option allows the restore to continue after the error but the failed rows will still be lost.

Is there a reason why you're using mysqldump rather than the backup command within ndb_mgm - which is an online operation? If using the native Cluster (on-line!) backup then you use the ndb_restore command to restore your data.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your suggestion. Actually, agree that it is not a good idea to using --fore to restore.  I do not use ndb_mgm BACKUP because I do not know this before. And plan to try to use ndb_mgm backup.